# Check targets of a specific phase of Maven build lifecycle of a project

Tags: java, maven, build, lifecycle

I would like to know if there are tools that tell you "what is run in each specific phase" of the Maven Build Lifecycle (for example if I set `JUnit` to run in `<phase>test</phase`, this tool should tell me that during `test`, `JUnit` is run).

One example is the [BuildPlan Maven Plugin](http://buildplan.jcgay.fr/), but for example I can't say "ok show me only the phase `integration-test`"

Or, in case, my real question would be "how to spot integration test in a Maven project", but I think it depends(?)

Answer (score 0):

See [buildplan:list-phase](http://buildplan.jcgay.fr/list-phase-mojo.html#phase)'s `<phase>` parameter:

> **<phase>**
>
> Display plugin executions only for the specified phase.